# Issue configuring WCF service reference for Windows 8.1 app - Config changes lost to References.cs

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8.1

I am trying to consume a WCF service in a Windows 8.1 app but I can't get the `references.cs` file to be generated as in the below example:

```
  public partial class WeatherSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MetroTestApp.WeatherService.WeatherSoap>, MetroTestApp.WeatherService.WeatherSoap {

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
```

My `Reference.cs` file (for a difference WCF service) is generated as follows:

```
    public partial class StoreServicesClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TMAPrivateStore.PrivateStoreApp.StoreServicesRef.IStoreServices>, TMAPrivateStore.PrivateStoreApp.StoreServicesRef.IStoreServices {

    public StoreServicesClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
```

As a result, if I make the necessary configuration changes (as per this blog 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx), they are lost when the service reference is updated. What is going wrong here? Is it something to do with my WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why proxy code generated today is different now to how it would have been 4 years ago when the article was written but the main two are:

1. The service has changed in that time
2. The version of visual studio you are using to generate the code is different to that used in the linked article.

Either of these things can cause the generated code to completely change - the code generation process, while ultimately deterministic, will nevertheless respond unpredictably to changes in the service itself and/or proxy generation tooling used.

Regardless, this should not prevent you from consuming the service, you just need to look for the `GetCityWeatherByZIPAsync()` service proxy operation in the generated code, and call it in process with an await or some similar async mechanic from within your metro app.